# if statement for tic tac toe on python ((graphics)) 3.6.0

Tags: python

Iam new at python an Iam trying to figure out this if statment for the tic tac toe game on python using graphics ... i need some help , thank you

```
 # this programe wil present  Tic Tac Toe game X , O
# in this code i will use  import tkinter to show a message box
from graphics import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from button import Button

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Tic Tac", 500,500)
    win.setBackground("dark red")
 #   win.setCoords(Point(0,0),Point(3,3))



    # text
    T = Text(Point(228,420.20),'Welcome to Tic Tac Toc game !')
    T.setFill("red")
    T.setStyle('bold')
    T.draw(win)
    input_box = Entry(Point(250,450),10)
    input_box.draw(win)
    txt = Text(Point(250,400),"")
    txt.draw(win)
    txt.setText(input_box.getText())







    # get mouse click to start the game and change to the next window

    Ck = win.getMouse()
    Ck.draw(win)

    # changing the intro and ask the user to put moe information

    T.setText('Enter your name please , then click anywhere to start!.')


    # 2 Mouse click
    Ck2 = win.getMouse()
    Ck2.draw(win)

    buttons=[]
    buttonWidth=100
    buttonHeight=100
    y=50
    for i in range(3):
        x=100
        for j in range(3):
            b = Button(Point(x,y), Point(x+buttonWidth,y+buttonHeight),"")
            buttons.append(b)
            b.draw(win)
            x += buttonWidth
        y+=buttonHeight


    while True:
        p = win.getMouse()
        for b in buttons:
            if b.clicked(p):
                b.setText("X")


# 0 1 2
# 3 4 5
# 6 7 8

            #check for X winner
            if (buttons[0] != "" and buttons[0].getText() == buttons[1].getText() == buttons[2].getText() or               


             buttons[0] != "" and buttons[0].getText() == buttons[3].getText() == buttons[6].getText()or



             buttons[0] != "" and buttons[0].getText() == buttons[4].getText() == buttons[8].getText()or


             buttons[0] != "" and buttons[1].getText() == buttons[4].getText() == buttons[7].getText()or

             buttons[0] != "" and buttons[2].getText() == buttons[5].getText() == buttons[8].getText()or

            buttons[0] != "" and buttons[3].getText() == buttons[4].getText() == buttons[5].getText()or

            buttons[0] != "" and buttons[6].getText() == buttons[7].getText() == buttons[8].getText()or

             buttons[0] != "" and buttons[2].getText() == buttons[4].getText() == buttons[6].getText()):
                tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('WE GOT A WINNER !', ' player X Won the game')




             # check for O winner

            b.setText('O')

            if buttons[0] != "" and buttons[0].getText() == buttons[1].getText() == buttons[2].getText():               
                break

            elif buttons[0] != "" and buttons[0].getText() == buttons[3].getText() == buttons[6].getText():
                break


            elif buttons[0] != "" and buttons[0].getText() == buttons[4].getText() == buttons[8].getText():
                break

            elif buttons[0] != "" and buttons[1].getText() == buttons[4].getText() == buttons[7].getText():
                break
            elif buttons[0] != "" and buttons[2].getText() == buttons[5].getText() == buttons[8].getText():
                break
            elif buttons[0] != "" and buttons[3].getText() == buttons[4].getText() == buttons[5].getText():
                break
            elif buttons[0] != "" and buttons[6].getText() == buttons[7].getText() == buttons[8].getText():
                break
            elif buttons[0] != "" and buttons[2].getText() == buttons[4].getText() == buttons[6].getText():
                break
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('WE GOT A WINNER !', ' player O Won the game')
```

main()

AND THIS IS THE OTHER CODE THAT IAM IMPRTING FROM:

```
    from graphics import *
class Button:
    '''This is a button class.'''
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, text):
        self.box = Rectangle(p1, p2)
        self.label = Text(Point((p1.getX()+p2.getX())/2,(p1.getY()+p2.getY())/2), text)
        self.p1 = Point(min(p1.getX(),p2.getX()),min(p1.getY(),p2.getY()))
        self.p2 = Point(max(p1.getX(),p2.getX()),max(p1.getY(),p2.getY()))
        self.drawn = False

    def draw(self, win):
        ''' draw this button to the window, and returns None.'''
        if self.drawn == False:
            self.box.draw(win)
            self.label.draw(win)
            self.drawn = True

    def undraw(self):
        if self.drawn:
            self.box.undraw()
            self.label.undraw()
            self.drawn = False

    def clicked(self, p):
        '''Returns True if p is inside the button. False otherwise.'''
        if self.p1.getX()<p.getX()<self.p2.getX():
            if self.p1.getY()<p.getY()<self.p2.getY():
                return True
        return False

    def isClicked(self, p):
        return self.clicked(p)

    def getText(self):
        """returns the label text."""

        return self.label.getText()

    def setText(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)
```

Comment: `buttons[0] != ""` doesn't look right to me... What if you do `buttons[0].getText() != ""` instead?

Comment: What if statement? The one in Button.clicked()?

Comment: yeah for the wining statment :

Comment: if (buttons[0] != "" and buttons[0].getText() == buttons[1].getText() == buttons[2].getText() or   .....